# Remap Ctrl+E to autocomplete file names in fish

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fish

I'm using Fish shell on Urxvt terminal.

I want to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as auto-completion key, what is done by pressing <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow key by default.

[image: Sample screenshot]

I'm not sure if it's shell's or terminal's feature to do so, but it's clearly not the same as what is done by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and also, I could not find myself such function name in manual of `fish`'s built-in `bind` command.

Comment: It's definitely a fish feature, not a rxvt one. It's called "autosuggestions": https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#autosuggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding your looking for is `forward-char`. Normally the <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> are bound to it and will accept a fish's suggestion. Note that this is different from an auto-completion, corresponding to `complete-and-search` and bound to <kbd>Tab</kbd> by default.

To add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to this list, you can do:

```
bind \ce forward-char
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not, at least for me. I've already mapped `forward-char` to check before asking, but it did not work as expected; and `Ctrl-F` has absolutely no effect for me either. It might be that URxvt conflicts with Fish in my setup, or something similar to that, if I'm not very wrong. What `forward-char` did for me was just moving one character right in Normal Mode of Fish, and it did not work for Insert Mode as well when explicitly mapping with `--mode`. I'm very confused about that :)

Comment: Weird indeed. I tested it in fish on urxvt and it works fine. Do you have a special configuration for urxvt?

Comment: I made an error in copying the bind command by the way. There is a backslash before "ce".

Comment: I removed my `Xresources` file and tried the command out of `tmux`, now it works. I'm not sure what caused the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, and for the command.